# Syntax Error at or near the word join

Tags: sql

I'm using the following Select statement to retrieve and count the total of each field across multiple tables. However when it comes to executing the statement i get the error "Syntax Error at or near the word join"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Query:**

```
Select CompanyStatus,Companyname,
        INNER JOIN Company on usersincompany.companyID=company.companyID,
                INNER JOIN company on users.companyID=Company.companyID,
                 INNER JOIN usersincompany on users.userid=usersincompany.userid,
                INNER JOIN users on userstatus.userstatudid=users.userstatusid,
                INNER JOIN users on project.companyid=users.companyid,
                INNER JOIN users on usersession.userid=users.userid,
                INNER JOIN project on template.projectid=project.projectid,
                INNER JOIN project on merchendisingarea.projectid=project.projectid,
                 INNER JOIN merchendisingarea on publishstatus.publishstatusid=merchendisingarea.publishstatusid,
             INNER JOIN template on merchendisingmodule.templateid=template.templateid,
        INNER JOIN company on companyaccountclassification.classificationtypeid=company.classificationtypeid,
sum(distinct users.userid) as TotalUsers,
sum(case when users.userstatusid =2 then 1 else 0 end) as Activeusers,
sum(case when users.userstatusid =3 then 1 else 0 end) as SuspendedUsers,
sum(distinct usersessionid) as TotalLogin,
sum(distinct merchendisingmoduleid) as CurrentModules,
count( merchendisingmodule.createddate) as Modulescreated,
count( merchendisingmodule.updateddate) as Modulesupdated,
sum(distinct merchendisingareaid) as Currentareas,
count( merchendisingarea.createddate) as AreasCreated,
count( merchendisingarea.updateddate) as Areasupdated,
sum(case when publishingstatus.publishstatusid =1 then 1 else 0 end) as SuccessPublished,
sum(case when publishingstatus.publishstatusid =3 then 1 else 0 end) as FailedPublished  

 from users,company,merchendisingmodule,merchendisingarea,publishingstatus, usersession       group by companystatus, companyname
```

Comment: you should move your `from` clause above your `join` ones...

Comment: What is your sql engine? mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgres?

Answer (score 6):

Why are there ',' between each joins? No commas needed!

Put it like:

```
    SELECT <COLUMNS> 
    FROM <TABLE1> 
    INNER JOIN <TABLE2> ON <JOIN FIELDS>
    INNER JOIN <TABLE3> ON <JOIN FIELDS>
    WHERE <FILTER CONDITIONS>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a base table to join on!

```
Select
    CompanyStatus,
        Companyname,
    INNER JOIN Compan...
```

Needs a first table

```
Select
    CompanyStatus,
        Companyname
    FROM some_table
    INNER JOIN Compan...
```

And also get rid of those commas!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing From clause in your query after Companyname

```
Select  CompanyStatus, Companyname .
                                  ^ from clause
```

General syntax for join is as ,

```
select column_name 
from Table_name 1
Inner/Left/Right/cross Join Table_name 2
ON condition
```